# Understanding spf=none is neither permitted nor denied by domain

Tags: email, spf, dkim

I use G Suite to host my business email and I set SPF and DKIM to ensure that no spoofing or un-authenticated emails get sent from my address.

I sent an email to one of my other addresses to make sure that the setup works, but this is what I got in the email headers:

```
Authentication-Results: mx.zoho.eu;
  dkim=pass;
  spf=none (zohomail.com: HIDDEN_IP_ON_PURPOSE is neither permitted nor denied by domain of MY_DOMAIN) smtp.mailfrom=MY_EMAIL@MY_DOMAIN
```

Is this what should happen after properly configuring SPF and DKIM?

**Update**

15 mins after posting this question and another email attempt, I now get a successful message:

```
spf=pass (zohomail.com: domain of MY_DOMAIN designates HIDDEN_IP_ON_PURPOSE as permitted sender)
```

I suppose this was because of a delay with DNS propagation.

But the question still remains. What was the original message about?

Comment: You might want to look into DMARC as well, since DKIM only authenticates an email for the domain you are signing for (i.e. the domain in the `d=` tag) and SPF only authenticates the domain used in the Bounce Address a.k.a. `Return-Path`. These can both be different from the domain used in the FROM field, which is shown to recipients in email clients. This FROM field is the one you want to protect against spoofing. That is what DMARC accomplishes, alignment between DKIM d= tag and/or SPF `Return-Path` domain

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Reinto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have an SPF record at all, it acts the same as if you had one that returned a `neutral` response, that is, that it neither permits (with an SPF `pass` response, what you're now getting) nor denies (with an SPF `fail` response) email to be sent from that IP. That's all.